# How to retrieve data from two different database in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

i have two database cvtl and cvtl_db , i need to write a single query to retrieve data from table A in cvtl and table B in cvtl_db.

Postgres is throwing error: cross database reference are not implemented

Comment: Use a foreign data wrapper: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html

Comment: ok thanks will try using it , but can i use DBLINK instead

Comment: That's another option. But the FDW will be more efficient

Comment: Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two ways:

1. Older tools.
   If you need to support older versions of PostgreSQL, use dblink or DBI-link.  These two provide robust support for cross-db queries across a number of PostgreSQL versions.  pl/proxy is another possibility.
2. Newer tools.
   The newer approach is to use foreign data wrappers.  This has more functionality (such as better transaction handling) and probably has more eyes in terms of support than dblink etc do today.